# With her lap full of newspapers

Tags: usage

Which of the following two sentences is more meaningful

> **With her lap full of newspapers** Amita was sitting with her husband on the steps of the temple when Bunty and Bitto came up.

> Amita  **with her lap full of newspapers** was sitting with her husband on the steps of the temple when Bunty and Bitto came up.

Where should I place the clause **with her lap full of newspapers** and why?

Comment: Either way the sentence is clumsy. What is the most important idea in the sentence? That her "lap was full" or that others approached? *Amita and her husband were reading (a pile of) newspapers on the steps of the temple when Bunty and Bitto came up.* Or perhaps you should consider setting the scene in a sentence of its own.

Comment: Actually this is a question sentence in my book where I have to choose only one of the options and no further context is provided

Comment: I agree with @WeatherVane: they're equally unnatural.

Answer (score 1):

You can place the clause in either location but it would be better to use commas, as follows:

> **With her lap full of newspapers,** Amita was sitting with her husband on the steps of the temple when Bunty and Bitto came up.

> Amita, **with her lap full of newspapers**, was sitting with her husband on the steps of the temple when Bunty and Bitto came up.

Answer (score 1):

Both are a bit awkward, simply because so much is happening in the sentence. The sentence

- introduces Amita,
- shows us there are newspapers on her lap,
- positions Amita next to her husband,
- and describes the action of people coming up.

An editor might suggest breaking it up into two sentences to make it clear which details are important at a given moment. However, since this scenario is given to you and not created by you, I would select the second option as "correct". Based purely on my intuition from my experience with literature, the second construction is more common:

**[Person]**, **[with brief description]**, was **[passive or ongoing action]** when **[event/momentary action]**.

The first construction would be acceptable if less was going on:

**[with brief description]**, **[person]** was **[action]**.

OR

When **[momentary action]**, **[person]** was **[passive/ongoing action]**

For example, "With her lap full of newspapers, Amita was sitting by her husband." Or, "When Bunty and Bitto came up, Amita was sitting by her husband."
Combining these makes the sentence clunky.

Whatever comes before the first comma is the focus, the subject of the sentence. The option that starts with "Amita," tells us the scene is centered on Amita, which is amended by the description of newspapers (to add detail to Amita in the scene), before continuing to tell us about what Amita was doing. The option that starts with newspapers puts our focus close up on Amita's lap and then amends that to zoom out to include the steps and position her by her husband. Zooming out again to show people coming up asks the reader to do too many mental operations within a sentence.